# Function on the unit disk

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

If I have a function defined on the unit disk $f:\mathbb D \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and I know the average value of $f$ on any chord of the unit circle, can I reconstruct $f$?

**Edit**: we assume $f$ is continuous

Comment: Define "average value"! And what are the assumptions on f? Measurable? Continuous? Integrable?

Comment: I was hoping an answer would suggest some good hypotheses :)

Comment: Well, for a sensible definition of "average" (like using an integral) you will first want the function to be measurable (or rather integrable). But without asking for things like continuity, you will have uniqueness at most up to a null set.

Comment: Well, on the points $x$ in the *boundary* ($\|x\|=1$), $f(x)$ is reconstructable, as $\displaystyle\lim_{y\to x}\frac{\int_x^y f}{\|y-x\|}$ where $y$ is on the boundary and the integral is meant along the chord (average). For the internal points.. I'm not sure..

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_transform . Short answer: yes.